# Database.Query System.QueryException: unexpected token: '('

Tags: apex, soql, batch

Trying to create batch apex where the query has a precedence where clause but I get query exception error, can someone help me?

```
String country = 'MX';
String stageCold = '99. Cold';
String query = 'SELECT SalesStage__c, ColdSince__c FROM Account WHERE ((ColdSince__c <: Dday.addMonths(-3) AND AccountCountry__c != :country) OR (ColdSince__c <: Dday.addMonths(-2) AND AccountCountry__c = :country))';
System.debug(query);
System.debug(Database.query(query));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SOQL, like what you have, can only take simple values in variable binds.

Things like `AccountCountry__c != :country` are fine.
Things like `ColdSince__c < :Dday.addMonths(-3)` and `ColdSince__c < :Dday.addMonths(-2)` are problematic.

It doesn't look to me like you need to be using dynamic SOQL here, so turning it into a normal (static) SOQL query (using square braces) is probably the way to go here.

Comment: But static SOQL is not supported in bacth apex, is it?

Comment: @AdnanZahry No, you can, and should, use inline (static) queries when possible. Database.getQueryLocator accepts either a String or an inline query.

Comment: `can only take simple values in variable binds` - so true and also excludes things like `:someOppo.CloseDate` -- no dots

Comment: thank you guys, I have tried and the code now works as expected